# #SUGBELUX - ExM and Undeclared data during lead-follow-up

Tags: support, status-completed, community-event

**Local Date/Time:** Thursday December 1st 2016 at 5:45PM

**UTC Date/Time:** Thursday December 1st 2016 at 4:45PM

**Location:** Interleuvenlaan 17A, Heverlee, Belgium

**Link to details:** http://www.meetup.com/Sitecore-User-Group-Belgium/events/231943604/

**Who to contact for information:** Ivan Lieckens or Kris Verheire

**Description:**
The SUG board members would like to welcome you to ninth Sitecore User Group event (BeLux). Time to dive a little deeper into the ExM module and shed some light on data usage and form drop-out tracking.

Comment: Added to board. Community Bulletin promotion begins on Nov 21 at 16:45.